# How to access a row into foreach in wso2ESB (Developer Studio)

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I'm integrating wso2dss 3.5 and wso2esb 4.9. In DSS, I created a DataService to get data from a database. Following the WSO2 Dashboard into DSS, I used the endpoint in my eclipse project (Developer Studio). The xml gerated by DSS is:

```
<elements xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <row>
      <name>nome1</name>
      <address>rua xalala das xalalas</address>
   </row>
   <row>
      <name>nome2</name>
      <address>ruas rms did sa</address>
   </row>
   <row>
      <name>nome3</name>
      <address>aldoas daso dasodsa</address>
   </row>
</elements>
```

So, in my ESB config project, there is this generated code:

```
<foreach expression="//ds:elements/ds:row" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <sequence>
      <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
          <p:Insert xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <xs:nome xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:nome>
            <xs:endereco xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:endereco>
          </p:Insert>
        </format>
        <args>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="/ds:row/name"/>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="/ds:row/address"/>
        </args>
      </payloadFactory>
      <log>
        <property expression="/ds:row/name" name="nome"/>
        <property expression="/ds:row/address" name="endereco"/>
      </log>
    </sequence>
  </foreach>
```

I'm trying to get the value of first and second element at each row (name and address). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add the xmlns:ds to args tag, like this:

```
<foreach expression="//ds:elements/ds:row" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <sequence>
      <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
          <p:Insert xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <xs:nome xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:nome>
            <xs:endereco xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:endereco>
          </p:Insert>
        </format>
        <args xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//ds:name"/>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//ds:address"/>
        </args>
      </payloadFactory>
      <log>
        <property expression="/ds:row/name" name="nome"/>
        <property expression="/ds:row/address" name="endereco"/>
      </log>
    </sequence>
  </foreach>
```

Comment: euahehaeuheaheuaheuah só comentei pra ver quanto tempo vc demoraria pra entrar no stack